# Speeding up python running multiple mysql queries

Tags: python, mysql, django

My python code produces a table with weeks as columns and rows as urls accessed. To get the data for each cell a query on a mysql database is executed. The code runs very slowly. I've added indexes to the mysql tables and this has not really helped. I thought it was because i was building the html table code with concatenation but even using a list and join has not fixed the speed. The code runs slowly in both django (using an additional database connection) and standalone python. Any help of speeding this up would be appreciated.

example query that to called from a loop:

```
def get_postcounts(week):
    pageviews = 0
    cursor = connections['olap'].cursor()
    sql = "SELECT SUM(F.pageview) AS pageviews FROM fact_coursevisits F INNER JOIN dim_dates  D ON F.Date_Id = D.Id WHERE D.date_week=%d;" % (week)
    row_count = cursor.execute(sql);
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in result:
       if row[0] is not None:
            pageviews = int(row[0])
    cursor.close()
    return pageviews
```

Comment: Your sql code seems incorrect - WHERE AND?

Comment: Have you tried optimizing the SQL, e.g. putting an index on f.date_id and d.id?. Also I agree with the answer by user1857805 - probably faster to read it in one large query with group by week, and the separate it out in Python

Comment: How big are those tables you are querying and what datatypes are you using to store the data? Also, what kind of hardware are you using to run the database server?

Comment: Have you tried doing what the answer suggested, specifically reading everything as one query, and then splitting it in python?

Comment: Turns out a good way to improve speed is too swap to a dataframe tool. Using Pandas I can do a lot more calculations and everything runs fast.

Answer (score 0):

it could be because of the number of queries that you are executing(if you are having to call this method a lot).

i would suggest querying view count and the week over a certain period in one single query and read off the results.